# Windows 10 IOT core virtual keyboard?

Tags: webview, uwp, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I working on IOT device, my touchscreen monitor does not have virtual keyboard. and my machine does not allow physical keyboard.

i already try code from 'digital signage', at first it only work single textfield.
with some little tweak on the code, i can use it for all my textbox.

my real problem is that now i'm using webview, and i need to input some data. in the webview i can't use the virtual keyboard from 'digital signage'.

is there anyone who have solution for this virtual keyboard that can be used on webview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may take some modification of the OnScreenKeyboard control, but here's the idea:

1. Capture the on-screen keyboard output
2. Use [WebView.InvokeScriptAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx) method to execute JavaScript on the web page loaded in the WebView
3. The JavaScript will get the focused textbox in the HTML
4. Set the value of the textbox to the keyboard output

Comment: do you have a little sample code?
as far as i know, InvokeScriptAsync can only used for executing function in  javascript on the site. i dont have control about code on the site inside webview. 

every sample code that i found in google,  the use of InvockeScriptAsync is like this **InvokeScriptAsync("function_name","arguments_array")**

Comment: The trick is to use the "eval" function like this: **WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "alert('hello world');" });**

Comment: This link may be helpful: https://www.suchan.cz/2016/01/hacking-uwp-webview-part-2-bypassing-window-external-notify-whitelist/